# What frameworks are used in this web-application?

Tags: javascript, web, html5-canvas

If somebody has stumbled upon something like [this](http://www.giantstepsmedias.com/) (I'm particularly interested in "chaotic" circles on the background that react on cursor) please respond. I'd very much like to know what JavaScript frameworks, that are able to implement something like this, you would recommend.

Btw is it even possible to create this without third-party code ?

Comment: http://threejs.org will help you do that.

Comment: Yes, this is fairly easily produced without 3rd party libraries. See the indicated duplicate answer showing how to "repel" particles away from the mouse and "attract" those particles back to their starting location when they stop being repelled by the mouse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your dev console to see what libraries they're using. For instance, you'll see that they're using [Zepto](http://zeptojs.com/) and [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/).

> Btw is it even possible to create this without third-party code ?

Of course. 3rd party code doesn't do anything differently than your own code could- other than save you time and effort.